# MongoDB - count > 0 but collection not contains any record

Tags: mongodb

I removed all records from collection but I have this situation:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find({}).count() --> **OUTPUT IS A NUMBER > 0**

db.getCollection('myCollection').find({}) --> **Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms**
```

why does this happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: two queries refer two different collections. (myCollection and cosmome_values)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the message !

Comment: @rodrigoap    
If the collection is empty I expect count() to return 0, but I obtain a number > 0

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen (just kidding). That's quite unusual. Are you sure it's the same collection?

Comment: @AlexP. I confirm that it is the same collection. I will try to understand the reason for this strange behavior

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using and what storage engine (if not using the default)? It is possible for the fast collection count (a count without a query predicate) to become [inaccurate after an unclean shutdown using the Wired Tiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown). Assuming you are using the WiredTiger storage engine (default in MongoDB 3.2+), try: `db.getCollection('myCollection').validate()` to correct the count.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie for your tip !

Answer (score -1):

`db.getCollection('myCollection').find({}).count();` return count of records , (type Number)

where as

`db.getCollection('cosmome_values').find({});` will return array of records , (type Array)

Comment: If the collection is empty I expect count() to return 0

Comment: I obtain a number > 0 !  :/

Comment: Just tested in my Mongo - everything works fine. Are you sure you have using the same database?